# Disabling left mouse click until all keys were sent

Tags: mouseevent, autohotkey

I have an AHK script, that is called from another application with a parameter:

```
text = %1%

WinWaitActive, foobar, , 5
if ErrorLevel {
  Exit
}

Sleep, 300
SendInput, %text%{Enter}
```

There can be issues if there is a click during the "sleep".  So I would like to enable a hotkey like:

```
LButton::return
```

...during the sleep to block the mouse.  The blocking should be disabled when the script finishes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable one or more keys within a thread temporarily by using a boolean variable:

```
; begin of thread 
; ...

LButton_disabled := true 

; do something, in this case:    
Sleep, 300
SendInput, %text%{Enter}

LButton_disabled := false

; ...

return ; end of thread 


#If (LButton_disabled)

    LButton::return

#If
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the script will be persistent, but I want it to exit after the main part ran.  I found a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem can be solved with `ExitApp`:

```
text = %1%

WinWaitActive, foobar, , 5
if ErrorLevel {
  ExitApp
}

Sleep, 300
SendInput, %text%{Enter}

ExitApp
return


LButton::return
```

Comment: Be sure to use the [text sendmode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text), and you probably also want to use the [`*` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard).